# out of bounds error repopulating array for objective c app (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dynamic-arrays

I am currently troubleshooting code written by another colleague that has an out of bounds error with the following code. it involves selecting an item in a UINavigatorController. It also involves use of coreData.

the code looks like this (some of the code had been remove for troubleshooting purposes and clarity)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// : so far no errors with these lines of code. indexPath returns [0,0] or [0,1];
NSLog(@" : *** DetailViewController/didSelectRowAtIndexPath() - executing method ..."); 
NSLog(@" : *** DetailViewController/didSelectRowAtIndexPath() - indexPath = %@",indexPath);

// : returns row number (as an integer)

NSLog(@": *** DetailViewController/didSelectRowAtIndexPath() indexPath.row  = %d",indexPath.row);

// : managedObject returns coreData information. 
// Directory *managedObject = (Directory *)[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// NSLog(@": *** DetailViewController/didSelectRowAtIndexPath() managedObject  = %@",managedObject);

// example return

/* 
  <Directory: 0x5919e50> (entity: Directory; id: 0x59195d0 <x-coredata://FE8A3A0C-A0E4-4E0E-A90D-8471227D2284/Directory/p3> ; data: {
  ID = 48;
  IsFile = 0;
  LastChanged = "2011-01-04 14:39:00 +0000";
  Name = "All Papers by Author";
  ParentID = 7;
  Type = pdf;
  } 
*/

 // : returns the ID value from the managed object
 self.num = [managedObject ID];
 NSLog(@": *** DetailViewController/didSelectRowAtIndexPath() self.num (managedObject.ID)  = %@",[managedObject ID]);


 NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:finalArray];

 // : finalArray has two elements when this method runs
 NSLog(@"eja: DetailViewController/didSelectRowAtIndexPath() finalArray length is %i",[finalArray count]);

 [self.finalArray removeAllObjects]; // releases the objects, but makes the array empty;

 // : finalArray after remove all objects runs
 NSLog(@"eja: DetailViewController/didSelectRowAtIndexPath() finalArray length is %i",[finalArray count]);

// ** THE OUT OF BOUNDS ERROR OCCURS HERE **
 [self.finalArray setArray:[self searchDatabase:[self.num intValue] withPredicate:@"ParentID"]];**


 // NSLog(@": DetailViewController/didSelectRowAtIndexPath() finalArray  is %@",self.finalArray); 

// ... more code here, but not relevant.

 // : release the temp NSMutable array

 [tempArray release];

 // : maybe release the finalArray?


}
```

When I debug the app, I believe finalArray is supposed to be cleared (removeAllObjects) and is supposed to be re-populated, but I get an out of bounds error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Not sure where the error is coming from, so looking for some advice and tips...

EDIT: i added a new trace statement after the removeAllObjects statement

```
// : finalArray after remove all objects runs
 NSLog(@"eja: DetailViewController/didSelectRowAtIndexPath() finalArray length is %i",[finalArray count]);
```

it returns a count of 0. So should I suspect then that because it has zero length it has no room to reallocate memory to add new items? I thought that was how Mutable arrays work (more or less).

EDIT 2: Instead of setArray, I also tried add ObjectsFromArray, replacing this:

```
[self.finalArray setArray:[self searchDatabase:[self.num intValue] withPredicate:@"ParentID"]];**
```

// with this

```
[self.finalArray addObjectsFromArray:[self searchDatabase:[self.num intValue] withPredicate:@"ParentID"]];
```

but I had a similar error returned (out of bounds)...

Comment: Please edit your post and use the provided "code" markup to make that example readable. As is it is very difficult to read your example to identify the problem. In addition please run your app in the debugger and identity which line triggers that exception (there's a "break on objective-c exceptions" option in the Xcode "run" menu which should help). Once you can identify the line responsible for your crash you should be much better prepared to identify the underlying cause.

Comment: I did run the debugger. the line of code causing the error was  [self.finalArray setArray:[self searchDatabase:[self.num intValue] withPredicate:@"ParentID"]]; . I have re-edited the code above to reflect this . thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Jonah i have edited the question to format it properly... :)

Comment: Much easier to read, thank you. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your use of arrays as shown so I'm afraid you need to keep hunting. What does that call to "searchDatabase:withPredicate:" return, is it the array you expected?

Comment: I guess you should check `-searchDatabase:withPredicate:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-setArray:` replaces the existing elements with the elements from the array you are passing in.  Thus the `-removeAllObjects` is redundant, but this is not the cause of your problem.

The size of the array you send `-setArray:` to is completely irrelevant so the problem probably lies in the array you are getting the elements from i.e. the one you get from:

```
[self searchDatabase:[self.num intValue] withPredicate:@"ParentID"]
```

I would separate that out by assigning a temp variable and then examine it in the debugger before the `-setArray:` and after the `-setArray:` (set the option "break on OBjective-C exceptions").

Comment: I am continuing investigation of this issue based upon your comments, and will keep the thread active.thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Jeremy I gave you a checkmark since your general troublehshooting tip led me in the correct path. thank you

Comment: @djeddiej: Thanks for the points.  However, technically, you should give the accept to the answer that best answers the question, even if it is your own.  Remember that it's not just about you getting the right answer to your question, but also about providing a knowledge repository for other people. So if you think your answer would bew of more help to people than mine, you should change your decision.

Answer (score 0):

I determined the answer to the issue (and it's kind of silly)... I should give some context to the code I wrote above.

The purpose of the code was to use a UINavigationController to display information about directories and files. The problem was in the logic of the code. finalArray was a list of what needed to be displayed (i.e. a list of directories or files) and tempArray held the current directory.

All I needed some additional code to address the length...

```
// the following code was placed BELOW the code listing in the original question

if  ([finalArray] count == 0){
  // other code here
  finalArray = tempArray; // reassign the current value (a list of files in this case) back to the current array...
} else {

  // we will assign finalArray with the value of TempArray first, as "we are not done recursing through"
  finalArray = tempArray;

  //  other code here

}
```

The out of bounds error showed up as a result of navigating through to a child view in UINavigationController and hitting the "back" button. since the display was not updated with the new menu items (whether it be files or folder listings) "finalArray" was constantly out of whack with what was actually being displayed (hence out of bounds - there may be 2 entries but maybe finalArray referenced one entry, whether it was a file or folder).

Hope this makes sense and thanks to all who looked at this question...

regards

Edward